# Ao registrar usuario, preciso que verifique no banco de dados se esse usuario ja existe e apresentar mensagem de erro

Tags: php, mysqli

Segue abaixo o meu código. Ele faz tudo, porém trava na mensagem de "usuário já cadastrado" mesmo eu inserindo no campo um usuário diferente!

**Observações:**

`$con` é a conexão ao banco de dados que esta correta;

login é o id no campo da pagina onde insere os dados;

uso mysqli;

a tabela é "usuarios"

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

#Recolhendo os dados do formulário
$loginrecolha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $login);
$senharecolha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $senha);

# Verificando apenas um campo, no caso login.
$sql = $con->query("SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login='$loginrecolha'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "Este usuário já existe";
exit();
} else {
 if(!$con->query("INSERT INTO usuarios (login,senha) VALUES 
('$login','$senha')")) die ('Os dados não foram inseridos');
 echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
}
```

Comment: Como assim trava na mensagem "usuário já existe"?Quer dizer que sempre cai no IF?

Comment: isso amigo... se eu cadastrar qualquer usuario existindo na tabela ou não cai no if

Comment: Se você pegar a instrução que está em `$sql` e executar no banco, ele encontra algum registro ?

Comment: sim encontra 1 registro que é o que tem

Answer (score 0):

Tente alterar o código desta forma:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

#Recolhendo os dados do formulário
$loginrecolha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $login);
$senharecolha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $senha);

# Verificando apenas um campo, no caso login.
$sql = $con->query("SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login='".$loginrecolha."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "Este usuário já existe";
exit();
} else {
 if(!$con->query("INSERT INTO usuarios (login,senha) VALUES 
('$login','$senha')")
   echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
 else
   die ('Os dados não foram inseridos')) 
}
```

Comment: opa, obrigado amigo mas continua caindo no "usuario ja existe" mesmo inserindo um que não exista... e o ultimo if alterado como solicitou deu esse erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in....